# dialog box is not triggering on second time click after ajax response loaded in dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

```
var value;
$("#multipleids").live("dblclick", function(){  
    value =$(this).attr('id');  
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "ajax.php",                        
        data:"value="+value,
        success: function(data){
            $("#dialog").html(data);
        }   
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog(
    {
        title: 'title',
        autoOpen:true,          
        closeOnEscape: true,
        width:500,
        height:500,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function() {             
            })
        }       
    });

});
```

hie...on click am opening a dialog box which contains the result of a ajax call..the dialog box is not opening on the second time click.When am using the autoOpen: false property...the dialog box is not at all displaying....can anyone suggest how to solve this this issue.Thanks.

Comment: i think jquery's html here creates a problem...try append or appendTo

Comment: html replaces your dialog content and also the classes and all set up by jquery.. rather using append or appendto create a div inside that inside your dialog and use html function on that element.. that will surely works..

Answer (score 0):

I changed part of your code, but don't have time to test it, my code almost likes this and works well. You can have a try:

```
var value;

var oTable=$("#dialog").dialog(
    {
        title: 'title',
        autoOpen:false,          
        closeOnEscape: true,
        width:500,
        height:500,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function() {             
            })
        }       
    });

$("#multipleids").live("dblclick", function(){  
    value =$(this).attr('id');  
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "ajax.php",                        
        data:"value="+value,
        success: function(data){
            oTable.dialog("open");
            oTable.createdDialog.html(data);
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code its not triggering second time..even i pryied this one alsocan u please tell me what wrong in this code y its not triggering on second click 
function popdialog(item){
     
value=$(item).attr("id");    
     tag = $(" <div ></div>");
         $.ajax({            
        type:"post",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data:"value="+value,
        success: function(data) {   
            tag.html(data).dialog({
                modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
        }
    });
    
}

Answer (score 0):

You Are Using Html of jquery which replaces jquery's setup to create jquery ui dialog and that is why you are not able to see dialog

what you have to do is create a div inside #dialog and then

```
$("#divinsideyour-dialog").html(markup)
```

Comment: <div id="folder"><div id="dialog"></div></div>when am using $("#dialog").html(data) in ajax success function....its triggering only 1 time with the ajax result in dialog div....and wen am using $("#folder dialog").html(data);its triggering multiple times but without data in dialog from ajax result

Comment: <div id="folder"><div id="dialog"><div id='ajaxContent'></div></div></div> and then success: function(data){
            $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
        }